# jQuery jPlayer.event.ended works in Chrome, Safari, IE9, but NOT Opera and FireFox

Tags: jquery, jplayer

I have pulled my hair out over this.
Normally when something doesn't work it is just IE.
But this doesn't work in FF and Opera.

In the following code playSound() is being called so all conditions are 
being met and a sound is playing.

However at the end of the sound the sound button etc is supposed to be reset with resetSound().

This works 100% in Chrome, IE9 and Safari.
Can anyone tell me why it wouldn't work in FF and Opera?

```
function clickSoundbtn(clicked) {
console.log('clickSoundbtn');
if (clicked != bucket['playing_now'] && clicked != bucket['current']) {
 console.log('clickSoundbtn');
$('#jquery_jplayer').unbind($.jPlayer.event.ended).bind($.jPlayer.event.ended, function() {
    console.log('resetting sound');
    resetSound(bucket['playing_now']);
    $('#jquery_jplayer').unbind($.jPlayer.event.ended);
    bucket = [];
    saiseichuu = [];
    });
playSound(clicked);
}
else
{
    if (bucket['current'])
    stopAll();
    else
    resetSound(clicked);
}
} // end of function: clickSoundbtn
```

Comment: hmm, i have a general feeling things could be refactored here.. anyway, more context would help.. The markup and jPlayer constructor options you're using would help us.. a Fiddle or link to the page would be *most* useful..

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was wrong.
This code was being called into a div via AJAX.

All the other code can remain in the parent script.
You must reinitialize the Jplayer inside the called AJAX script.

**Step 1:** The code to initialize the player is in the CALLED script.

```
my_jPlayer = $("#jquery_jplayer");
my_jPlayer.jPlayer({
swfPath: "/javascript/Jplayer.swf",
wmode: "window"
```

**Step 2:** The player div is also included in the called script.

```
<div id=jquery_jplayer></div>
```

**Step 3:** Make sure the my_jPlayer variable is assigned in the parent script as a global.

```
var my_jPlayer;
```